# I can't receive ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_FINISHED intent

Tags: android, android-broadcastreceiver

I want to receive the ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_FINISHED, but it doesn't work.
Below is my manifest about receiver.

```
<receiver android:name=".MyReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_SCANNER_FINISHED" />
        <data android:scheme="file" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

I've browsed through many related articles, but there is no correct answer and most of them are quite old.
I wonder whether it is related with API level or device or system app?

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/RdvA7y4MqfE .. go for it

Comment: I've seen this one and added <data> element.